# Golang goroutine memory leak

Tags: go

I can't understand why memory is not freed. Memory profile shows that almost all of the memory used by **runtime.malg**. If I remove range over channel in DoSomeWork everything works fine.

Here of the output of fmt.Println:

```
Memory Acquired:  4196600
Memory Used    :  745192

Memory Acquired:  2651299576
Memory Used    :  393923440
```

Source code:

```
func DoSomeWork(work chan int) {
    for _ = range work {
    }
}

func main() {
    k := make(chan int)
    m := &runtime.MemStats{}
    runtime.ReadMemStats(m)
    fmt.Println("Memory Acquired: ", m.Sys)
    fmt.Println("Memory Used    : ", m.Alloc)

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    // generate a lot of goroutines that reads from channel
    for i:=0;i<1000000;i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            DoSomeWork(k)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    close(k)
    wg.Wait()

    // make GC
    runtime.GC()

    // show memory after garbage collector
    runtime.ReadMemStats(m)
    fmt.Println("Memory Acquired: ", m.Sys)
    fmt.Println("Memory Used    : ", m.Alloc)
}
```

Comment: The job of the garbage collection isn't to free memory. Is it `m.Sys` you're concerned about?

Comment: Why? That's how much heap memory you've used. Again GC doesn't free memory, the heap scavenger does. I'd be more concerned that you've allocated 2GB of stack.

Comment: 2.6GB of stacks*, 1000000 stacks, 2.6KB average per stack.

Comment: @thwd: Goroutine stacks start at exactly 2K, with no need to grow here either, and the rest is all heap. BTW, those stacks will be reclaimed now when the scavenger runs, so this proc's RSS will drop back down to the 400-500MB of heap that's left. I'm actually curios as to what is left on the heap. I assume some normally negligible bookkeeping that only shows up with way too many goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no memory leak in your code. However you do cause a lot of memory to be reserved and that's what you see.

When i look for any kind of leak i prefer to do the test more then once. This is easily done whit your code. Just add:

```
func init(){
    for{
        main()
    }
}
```

The new output will reveal that no memory was lost during the run:

```
Memory Acquired:  2885880
Memory Used    :  14848
Memory Acquired:  2594885728
Memory Used    :  297108312
Memory Acquired:  2594885728
Memory Used    :  297108984
Memory Acquired:  2624143456
Memory Used    :  297108312
Memory Acquired:  2624143456
Memory Used    :  297108984
Memory Acquired:  2624143456
Memory Used    :  297108312
Memory Acquired:  2624143456
Memory Used    :  297108984
Memory Acquired:  2624143456
Memory Used    :  297108312
Memory Acquired:  2624143456
Memory Used    :  297108984
Memory Acquired:  2624143456
Memory Used    :  297108312
```